# How to align elements of two matrices horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, matrices, columns

I'd like to position two matrices under each other so that the columns of the matrices are rendered under each other, too. An example what I'd like to have:

```
  |100 200|
A=| 30  3 |
  | 1  119|

b=[ 1   0 ]
```

I've tried this:

```
\begin{align*}
    A= &\begin{vmatrix}
        100 & 200 \\
        30 & 3\\
        1 & 119
    \end{vmatrix}\\
    b= &\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

...but it only aligns the = signs, but not the columns of the two matrices. What's the trick? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the numbers should be right-aligned in the respective columns. If that's the case, you could

- use `{vmatrix*}[r]` environments and employ suitably chosen `\phantom` directives to "pad" the numbers in the `b` row vector with invisible zeros; or
- load the `siunitx` package and use its `S` column type inside `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for 'vmatrix*' and 'align*' env.
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    A&= \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        100 & 200 \\
        30 & 3\\
        1 & 119
    \end{vmatrix*}\\
    b&= \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        \phantom{00}1 & \phantom{00}0
    \end{vmatrix*}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    A&= \left\lvert 
        \begin{array}{@{}*{2}{S[table-format=3.0]}@{}}
        100 & 200 \\
        30 & 3\\
        1 & 119
        \end{array} 
        \right\rvert\\
    b&= \left\lvert 
        \begin{array}{@{}*{2}{S[table-format=3.0]}@{}}
        1 & 0
        \end{array} 
        \right\rvert
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: b should be `[]` not `||` (which makes it a bit harder:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - A lot harder, at least for ordinary mortals. Let's see if the OP weighs in.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! The `[]` was no problem :) I prefer the 2nd solution, as I have lots of such matrix-pairs, and its hard to "phantom" them manually. I've played for a while to see if I can make the numbers centered instead of right-aligned (actually decimal-dot-right-aligned), as is the default for an ordinary `bmatrix`, but it seems that `siunitx` does not support that. Anyway, I'm happy with the result.

Comment: Someone has also proposed in a comment the usage of `\mathmakebox`. Now the comment seems to be deleted, but I've liked that idea, too. I personally like it better than the `\phantom` solution. Let it stand here for future reference: `\mathmakebox[\widthof{200}][c]{0}` once in a column (requires `\usepackage{calc}`).

Comment: @KrisztianNemeth if the alignment os Ok for you then fine, but the reason I said it was harder is that `[` is wider than `|` so the columns will not be aligned even if they have the same widths if the delimiters have different widths.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. I indeed had a problem: using a _higher_ matrix made the `[` and the space around it _wider_. So for the proper alignment I've added same `\hspace`s manually for the row vector. Hope the gods of LaTeX will forgive me...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mico's solution, the tricky bit with using `bmatrix` is that the brackets get wider as they get taller.  I use a savebox to measure the width without having to enter the code twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for 'bmatrix*'
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{$222$}% adjust to fit

\newcommand{\Rcolumn}[1]{\mathmakebox[\mywidth][r]{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\Rcolumn}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix*}[R]
        100 & 200 \\
        30 & 3\\
        1 & 119
    \end{bmatrix*}$}
\begin{align*}
    A&= \usebox{\tempbox}\\
    b&= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox][c]{\begin{bmatrix*}[R]
        1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix*}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]