# Aligning two matrices's values (one on top of the other)

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays, brackets

It's kinda hard to explain what I want so here's the code and the result:

```
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{matrix}
    {} & \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \cdots & n-1 \end{pmatrix} \\
    \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\  1 \\ \vdots \\ n-1 \end{pmatrix} &
        \begin{pmatrix}
        f(0,0)&f(0,1)&\cdots&f(0,n-1)\\
        f(1,0)&f(1,1)&\cdots&f(1,n-1)\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
        f(n-1,0)&f(n-1,1)&\cdots&f(n-1,n-1)
        \end{pmatrix}
   \end{matrix}
\end{gather*}
```

[image]

What I wanted is for the upper matris to be equally formatted as the big one below. So "0" shoud be aligned with "f(0,0)", "1" with "f(0,1)" and so on. I don't think I can use arrays since that wouldn't be able to use brackets. A solution would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365596/how-to-align-elements-of-two-matrices-horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix; use `\makebox[\widthof{<last row cell>}]{<first row cell>}`. This requires the `calc` package to compute `\widthof`.

```
 \begin{gather*}
    \begin{matrix}
    {} & \begin{pmatrix}\makebox[\widthof{$f(n-1,0)$}]{0} & \makebox[\widthof{$f(n-1,1)$}]{1} & \cdots & \makebox[\widthof{$f(n-1,n-1)$}]{$n-1$}\end{pmatrix} \\[.2em]
    \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\  1 \\ \vdots \\ n-1 \end{pmatrix} &
        \begin{pmatrix}
        f(0,0)&f(0,1)&\cdots&f(0,n-1)\\
        f(1,0)&f(1,1)&\cdots&f(1,n-1)\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
        f(n-1,0)&f(n-1,1)&\cdots&f(n-1,n-1)
        \end{pmatrix}
   \end{matrix}
\end{gather*}
```

> [image]

Comment: You might want to use \mathmakebox from mathtools (\widthof is included).  This is the approach used by \vdotswithin.